# Angular - expression in templates view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

I'm new to angular, trying to make a SPA.
Just include the route module, and it works fine, but the templates inside don't process angular expression, just put one inside " {{ 1 + 2 }} ".
And shows me the exact same expression and not "3".

Do i need to make anything else to make templates run expressions?

My code:
index.html

```
<!HTML>
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Prueba">
    <div class="Contenido" ng-view></div>
</body>
<script>
    angular.module('Prueba', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'vista2.html',
        controller: 'prCtrl'        
    })
});
</script>
</HTML>
```

vista2.html

```
<div>{{ 1+2 }}</div>
```

Comment: Though its not your answer, but where is `prCtrl ` controller? its not defined here and no extra javascript is loaded. Do you get any error message in console?

Comment: Your error is elsewhere, the expression is fine.

Comment: prCtrl is not defined, im getting this error:

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=prCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Sb (http://localhost/angular/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at tb (http://localhost/angular/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at http://localhost/angular/angular.min.js:75:331
    at A.link (http://localhost/angular/angular.route.js:7:268)
    at $ (http://localhost/angular/angular.min.js:70:149)

maybe is an dist issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is fine. You should define prCtrl as controller and it should work just fine.
such expresions as :

- 1+2
- a+b
- user.name
- items[index]

are valid in angular and you can use them in {{ }} brackets. Your problem is lack of controller, that is why expresions are not parsed correctly.

Expressions are described in [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/guide/expression).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 'prCtrl' controller.
Simply add this line at the end of your script:

```
angular.module('Prueba').controller('prCtrl', function($scope){});
```

And it should work.